# etoken, .net, криптопровайдер, установка сертификата с закрытым ключом в хранилище

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

Можно ли при работе с сертификатом с закрытым ключом(etoken) обойтись без установки криптопровайдера (CryptoPro CSP) на сервер?

Для выполнения этой задачи был сделан экспорт сертификата с закрытым ключом через CryptoPRO CSP, в результате получился контейнер формата .pfx. Далее сертификат из созданного контейнера был установлен в хранилище.

Но при обращении к этому сертификату

```
X509Store store = new X509Store( "MY",StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection found = store.Certificates
    .Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "XXX", false);
X509Certificate2 certificate = found[0];
```

свойство `certificate.PrivateKey` == null.

Comment: Предлагаю восстановить [ответ](/a/484264/178988).

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я помню своё общение с CryptoPro, то без его установки не выйдет. Если вы попробуете посмотреть установленный сертификат через certmgr, то увидите, что он не валидный. Это происходит из-за того, что сертификаты CryptoPro подписываются ГОСТ-овскими алгоритмами, которых нет по умолчанию в Windows. В этом и суть крипто-провайдера. Он предоставляет новый алгоритм шифрования в систему (стандартными средствами). Так что только после его установки сама Windows сможет определить алгоритм используемый для подписи и показать сертификат как валидный. Соответственно и ваш код должен бы заработать после.